Decrypting a file encrypted with S.S.E ,based on AES-256
While backing up data of my phone, i had encryted the data with an android app called SSE encrypter, It's algorithm is explained here
It has Aes-256 as its default mode.
I have forgotten the password since it was backed-up some time back.
Now i wish to decrypt by brute forcing the password.,As I had set the password, I have some idea what it the length and characters being used. So typically I have to open their app and try password one by one. Since this encryption algorithm AES is universal, can I write a python program to Brut force the password. Once again I like to clarify that in no way I intend to break the algorithm, rather brute force my password as it was around 8 characters in length.
Also it says it has a test bytes of code, which can be used to check the password. But I'm still not clear how exactly to write a program to brute force the password.
Question is well researched, I have looked up possible solutions(brute forcing password, Not the encryption), I have looked up and posted the algorithm used for this specific file.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"looking for ideas"? What research have you done regarding this, and what have you tried so far? "Brute force" can mean a variety of things; can you clarify what you are intending to try to force brutally? The password (probably the better option for a personal with normal compute resources), the actual encryption (probably requires a super computer, to be realistic), something else? Also, please note that your question has significant basic formatting issues. As you EDIT your post to add information to it, take the time to review and correct the formatting.

Please check it now, the question is well researched, I'm not asking a one liner , with just my question, rather it has the clues which I think can help

With an 8 character password, good luck brute-forcing it before the heat death of the universe!! AES-256 alone is infeasible to brute-force, if the key is more than a couple of characters.

You're not getting my point, since I have set the password, i know which character i usually use, so the letters and symbols I'll be working with is very less
